# Robber's language backwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x

does anyone know how to translate robber's languge to English in python?

like this one but in reverse?

```
def translate(s):
  consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
  return ''.join(a + 'o' + a if a in consonants else a for a in s)

print(translate("hej"))
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: The example i've shown above was the code for translating something to robber's language, hey=hoheyoy

Comment: But i'm trying to traslate from Robber's language to English

Comment: I've tried writing the same code like this one but instead removing 'o' and the consonant, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes; so what? This isn't a code-writing service. Give a [mcve] with a better explanation of the problem than *"doesn't seem to work"*.

Comment: Given the above code how do you get "hoheyoy" from "hey"? Shouldn't it be just "hohey"?

Comment: @IljaEverilä You seem to be right, I get the same [here](https://ideone.com/ac8GVw).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
def translate(s):
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    counter = 0
    outputcounter = 0
    output = s
    while counter < len(s):
        char = s[counter]
        if char in consonants:
            output = output[:outputcounter] + char + output[outputcounter + 3:]
            counter += 3
            outputcounter += 1
        else:
            counter += 1
            outputcounter += 1
    return output
```

Try it out! (I don't know if that's nice code style, but however)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an alternative approach**

Since this is an interesting problem, I decided to have a go myself. Here is an efficient way of writing your first function with `O(1)` set lookup:

```
def translate_english_robber(s):
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'

    # using a set instead is more efficient
    lookup = set(consonants + consonants.upper())

    result = ""
    for char in s:
        if char in lookup:

            # anonymous function for converting the case of the letter "o"
            convert_case = lambda x: "o" if x.islower() else "O" 

            # add it to the result
            result += char + convert_case(char) + char
        else:
            result += char

    return result
```

Then for the reverse translation, all you need to do is find a consonant, and append it to the list, then somehow remove the next 2 characters, and continue the next iteration after the last removed character. Otherwise, if the current character is not a constant, add it normally.

For example, If my Robbers language was `"hohey"`, I would first find `"h"`, add it, and remove `"o"` and `"h"` after that, then start iterating from `"e"`. In the end, we would have `"hey"` as the English translation.

Using an iterator would be useful here. You can also read up on iterators [here](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-generators-and-iterators-du1082iua), they are quite useful for problems like this.

Here is my attempt:

```
def translate_robber_english(s):
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    lookup = set(consonants + consonants.upper())

    # create the iterator
    it = iter(list(s))

    result = ""

    # loop till we reach the end
    while True:
        try:
            # get the current letter
            current = next(it)

            # add it regardless
            result += current

            # if consonant, skip the next to letters
            if current in lookup:
                next(it)
                next(it)

        # If this exception occurs, break out of the loop
        except StopIteration:
            break

    return result
```

And now you can get the reverse translations with both the above functions:

```
>>> robber = translate_english_robber("black")
>>> print(robber)
boblolacockok
>>> english = translate_robber_english(robber)
>>> print(english)
black
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
def reverse_translate(s):
    vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    final = []
    for i in range(len(s)):

        if s[i] in vowel:
            final.append(s[i])

        else:

            try:
                if s[i] == s[i + 2]:
                    final.append(s[i:i + 3])
            except IndexError:
                pass

    for j, i in enumerate(final):
        if i == 'o':
            try:
                if final[j] == final[j + 1]:
                    pass
                else:
                    del final[j]
            except IndexError:
                del final[j]

    return "".join(list(map(lambda x: x[0], final)))
```

Now test_cases:

Normal test_case:

```
print(reverse_translate('boblolacockok'))
```

output:

```
black
```

But if text also include 'o' as vowel now :

```
print(reverse_translate('boblolocockok'))
```

output:

```
block
```